# I need some tips on implementing the chroot command in C

Tags: c, chroot

I am tasked with writing  a simple shell along with these three commands: "nl", "head", "chroot"(with no parameters). I've written nl.c and head.c but I don't know where to start with the chroot.c. I've read what chroot does, googled some documentation and to me as a beginner this is complicated.

Any advice on this matter?

Comment: And what `chroot` without any parameters should do?

Comment: i need to implement chroot with no parameters just with arguments. I have to write it in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chroot` without an argument just prints an error message. You can use `printf` for that.

Otherwise, chroot calls [`chroot`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chroot), [`chdir("/")`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/chdir) and then executes a shell with one of the [`exec*`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) functions.

Comment: It also must properly drop root privileges using the setre*id() functions to change the real/effective IDs. Otherwise any simple program can perform a privilege escalation to recover the root's candy.